# Not able to add sublayout because of Sitecore Rocks

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-rocks

I am getting following error when I m trying to add a sublayout, after Installing Sitecore Rocks :

> Error: this template attempted to load component assembly
>   ‘Sitecore.Rocks.TemplateWizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c9e2eeb5a3dd9908, processorArchitecture=MSIL‘. For more
>   information on this problem and how to enable this template, please
>   see documentation on Customizing Project Templates.

Please provide a solution.

Comment: Did you solve this issue??? If you did, accept the answer.

Comment: yes jay! the solution provided by Jakob solved the problem.

Comment: I know this is old but I came across this post with the same issue, and VS could not access this assembly unless it was running in Administrator mode. So checking permissions can also be a benefit to you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to copy the assembly manually.

- Open Bin folder of your webRoot (e.g. C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Website\bin)
- If the assembly is not in Bin folder, Go to "c:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Extensions\" folder. Then, there would be some folders and find the assembly in one of folders.
- Copy ”Sitecore.Rocks.TemplateWizard.dll” and paste it to “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies”

Comment: Hi Jay, I could not find "Sitecore.Rocks.TemplateWizard.dll" anywhere. Neither in bin nor in Assemblies folder. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Go to "c:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Extensions\" folder. Then, there would be some folders and find the assembly in one of folders.

In my case, I could fine it in "C:\Users\jay\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Extensions\otmwsy1s.rzv\"

Comment: Hi Natasha. You can locate the Template Wizard by opening the Sitecore Start Page (from the Sitecore menu) and selecting Sitecore Rocks (in left side) and then under Send Feedback, select Open Sitecore Rocks application folder...

Comment: Restart Visual Studio if it's running